# Logout button in ArcGIS Web Application

Tags: javascript, arcgis, logout, esri

I have created a web application using webappbuilder in ArcGIS. Now I want a logout button to explicitly logout the application.

I have customized a widget which redirect my page to specific url but not clear the session.

```
    onOpen: function(){

          localStorage.clear();
          window.location = "https://irgeoportal.gov.in/arcgisportal/home/signin.html";
          console.log('onOpen');
        },

Also tried, 

session.abandon();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
Session.Clear();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Nothing is working

Please help!!!

Comment: have you looked at identity manager? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/identitymanager-amd.html

Comment: yes..but have no idea how to use it